# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: For those wondering why the current moderators haven't nominated themselves: the [election announcement](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/709/800) pointed out that there is no need for the current moderators to do this. (If this were a graduation election, the current moderators would need to nominate themselves.)