# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Language Learning Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **October 17** to bring in 2 more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on October 17, users can [nominate themselves](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On October 24, if there are 3 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on November 1 (or November 8, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Comment: For reference, there's the post [Graduation election: interest check](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/742) (from 3 months ago); for that post, it was just Tsundoku and I showing interest.