# Language Learning is graduating on 16 December

Tags: discussion, site-health

Good news! Language Learning Stack Exchange will be graduating on 16 December and join the other graduated sites on the Stack Exchange network.

So, what is going to change?

1. We will **lose the Beta label** that we have been "wearing" for more than 2050 days.
2. There will be a graduation election. This will be the first election for **all moderator positions** since April-June 2016, when [the selection process was less formal](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/800). (The [election that ran in June of this year](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/709/800) was for just one moderator position, not for the entire moderator team.) This election will be organised in 2022 or even early 2023. In that election, anyone who wants to become a moderator on the graduated site (including the current moderators) will need to nominate themselves. Many other sites will be graduating (see e.g. [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1622/2191)), so a specific date for the election can't be given yet.
3. There will be a **post on Meta Stack Exchange** similar to the [post about the graduation of 29 beta sites in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/340816).
4. We will probably **lose the "Site Stats" on the home page** and the link to the additional statistics on Area 51. (This was not stated explicitly, but that's what happened on the sites that graduated in 2019.)

And what will remain the same?

1. The **site design** will remain the same for the time being. Custom site designs haven't been created for many years. (See [When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368463/340816) on Meta Stack Exchange.)
2. The **[privilege reputation levels](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)**. (See this [question about differentiates newly graduated sites from beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331751/340816) and the comments by staff members below it.)

---

I would like to take this opportunity to thank everyone who has contributed to this site: the people who have moderated the site so far — [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy), [Tom Au](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/46/tom-au), [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet), [Quill](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/8/quill) and [fi12](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/fi12) —; all the users who have contributed great questions and answers on the main site; everyone who has contributed to the upkeep and moderation of the site by going through the review queue, contributing to meta discussion or editing tag wiki excerpts; and the CMs (Community Managers), who have mainly worked behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have been tracking data about the site for several years, I can't resist posting some data about the site at the time of its graduation:

#### Top Non-Language Tags

1. [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods): 304 questions
2. [resource-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request): 167 questions
3. [self-learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning): 141 questions
4. [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request): 116 questions
5. [vocabulary](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary): 99 questions
6. [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources): 90 questions
7. [pronunciation](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation): 87 questions
8. [grammar](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar): 74 questions
9. [teaching-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-methods): 64 questions
10. [reading](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading): 61 questions
11. [speaking](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking): 53 questions
12. [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources): 49 questions
13. [online-learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-learning): 43 questions
14. [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening): 42 questions
15. [anki](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anki): 38 questions
16. [writing-system](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-system): 38 questions
17. [teaching](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching): 37 questions
18. [dictionary](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary): 33 questions
19. [language-comparison](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison): 31 questions
20. [effectiveness](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness): 31 questions
21. [spaced-repetition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaced-repetition): 29 questions
22. [writing](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing): 27 questions
23. [children](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children): 27 questions
24. [l2-aquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l2-aquisition): 24 questions
25. [native-language](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-language): 24 questions

#### Top Languages in the Tags

1. [english](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) 102 questions
2. [multiple-languages](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages): 89 questions
3. [chinese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese): 77 questions
4. [spanish](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish): 44 questions
5. [german](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german): 37 questions
6. [japanese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese): 33 questions
7. [french](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french): 31 questions
8. [arabic](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic): 29 questions
9. [russian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian): 28 questions
10. [hebrew](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew): 27 questions

#### Reputation Leagues

According to the [reputation leagues page for our site](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/646/week/languagelearning), we have the following numbers of users above certain reputation thresholds:

| Total Rep | Users |
| --- | --- |
| 25,000+ | 0 |
| 10,000+ | 1 |
| 5,000+ | 3 |
| 3,000+ | 7 |
| 2,000+ | 9 |
| 1,000+ | 27 |
| 500+ | 63 |
| 200+ | 221 |
| 1+ | 7,340 |

###Most Prolific Posters###

The tables below are based on the [Area 51 statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning), which are no longer being updated.

All posts:

| User | Posts |
| --- | --- |
| [Tsundoku](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/) | 339 |
| [fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/) | 108 |
| [AML](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/4939/) | 102 |
| [Tommi](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/3595/) | 100 |
| [Anthony Pham](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/) | 73 |
| [Peter M. - stands for Monica](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/695/) | 58 |
| [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/) | 47 |
| [Rebecca J. Stones](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2795/) | 44 |
| [K Man](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7057/) | 42 |
| [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) | 40 |
| [Andrew Grimm](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/113/) | 39 |
| [michau](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/740/) | 39 |
| [Tom Au](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/46/) | 38 |
| [Antonio D.](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7420/) | 28 |
| [К. Келлогг Смиф](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2537/) | 25 |
| [Robert Columbia](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2167/) | 25 |
| [Blaszard](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/304/) | 24 |
| [Vitaly](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/3259/) | 24 |
| [gaeguri](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/133/gaeguri) | 23 |
| [bytebuster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/60/) | 20 |

Questions:

| User | Questions |
| --- | --- |
| [Tsundoku](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/) | 107 |
| [AML](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/4939/) | 42 |
| [Rebecca J. Stones](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2795/) | 36 |
| [fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/) | 34 |
| [Andrew Grimm](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/113/) | 33 |
| [Tommi](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/3595/) | 29 |
| [Blaszard](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/304/) | 23 |
| [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) | 22 |
| [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/) | 20 |
| [Anthony Pham](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/) | 11 |
| [successive suspension](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7388/) | 11 |
| [K Man](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7057/) | 10 |
| [Robert Columbia](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2167/) | 10 |
| [wythagoras](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/40/wythagoras) | 10 |
| [Growler](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2746/growler) | 10 |

Answers:

| User | Answers |
| --- | --- |
| [Tsundoku](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/800/) | 232 |
| [fi12](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/91/) | 74 |
| [Tommi](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/3595/) | 71 |
| [Anthony Pham](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/64/) | 62 |
| [AML](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/4939/) | 60 |
| [Peter M. - stands for Monica](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/695/) | 50 |
| [michau](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/740/) | 35 |
| [Tom Au](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/46/) | 34 |
| [K Man](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7057/) | 32 |
| [Antonio D.](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/7420/) | 28 |
| [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/) | 27 |
| [К. Келлогг Смиф](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/2537/) | 25 |
| [Vitaly](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/3259/) | 24 |
| [gaeguri](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/133/gaeguri) | 21 |
| [bytebuster](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/60/) | 20 |
| [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy) | 18 |